# Show Cumulative density function

Tags: probability, statistics

$$F(x)=1-exp(-ax^B)$$ for x>=0 , a>0, B>0 and F(x)=0 for x<0. Show that F is a cumulative distribution function and find the corresponding density.

Anyone can guide me for this question? I am not sure to use what criteria to prove that it is a cdf.

Then for second part, I differentiate the function and get $$aBexp(-ax^B)$$ but is different from the given answer, not sure where get wrong.

Anyone can help? Appreciate!
Thank you

Comment: Cumulative density function must have 3 properties $F(-\infty)=0$, $F(\infty)=1$ and $F'(x)\geq1$.

Comment: Of course, focus on $x > 0$. But try differentiating again.

Comment: @MrYouMath $F'(x)\ge1$ is wrong (first $\ge1$ should read $\ge0$, second $F'$ need not exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cumulative density function must have 3 properties

$F(-\infty)=0$: This is true because $F(x)=0$ for all $x<0$

$F(\infty)=1$: This is true as $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=1$.

$F'(x)\geq0$:

$$F'(x)=aBx^{B-1}\exp{(-ax^B)}>0$$

You can work out the details. But $F(x)$ is a CDF.

Comment: F'(x)>=0 right? the 3rd properties

Comment: Yes, edited my answer

Comment: No $F'$ must not exist for $F$ to be a CDF (I wonder why neither the asker nor the answerer can be bothered to *check* the properties of a CDF).

Comment: Why? that would mean the F'(x) is not differentiable? If this is a continous variable, shoulnt it be monotonic?

Comment: @Did Could you please give an appropriate answer?

Comment: I strongly suggested to check a reference, why didn't you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties (And yes, monotonic does not imply differentiable.)

Comment: it says non decreasing ($F'(x)\geq 0$, for differentiable function) and right contnious(automatically true as $F(x)$ is differentiable for alle $x$).

Comment: @Did: the confusion lies in the false statement that "$F'$ must not exist" when what I think you meant was "$F'$ need not exist (e.g. if the distribution has a singular component)".

Comment: @robjohn Why introduce some confusion where there is none? "$F'$ must not exist" means that it is not true that "$F'$ must exist".

Comment: @Did: no, there is a definite difference. "$F'$ must not exist" is not the negation of "$F'$ must exist".

Comment: @MrYouMath If you mean that the CDF in the question is differentiable everywhere, this is almost true. If you mean that every CDF is differentiable then no. (But apparently you now *discovered* the precise characterization on the WP page I linked to, and this is a good thing.)

Comment: @robjohn So let me rephrase: "It is not true that $F'$ must exist for $F$ to be a CDF". Which probably should be stated more simply as: "Not every CDF is differentiable".

Comment: @Did: which is simply "$F'$ need not exist", as I said before.